# Week wireless signal in Linux mint

Tags: wireless, hp, mint, signal

After installing Linux Mint 18.3 "Sylvia" - Cinnamon (64-bit) on my HP laptop, I realize that the WiFi signal is a way too weak and the modem and the router is near my laptop.

Model: HP Probook 4540s

Comment: I'm impressed that you were able to ask and answer your own question in under 60 seconds.

Comment: @rtaft There's nothing wrong with that, you can post question and answer simultaneously (as OP did here presumably): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwmly.png, and it's very much encouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the network card of this HP model seems to have just one antenna (instead of two). So, the driver had it wrong, what antenna is connected and where.

Solution: with the driver already installed try this on the command line:

```
$ sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
$ sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```

and

```
$ sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
$ sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
```

and see which of the two will get you a strong wifi signal.

Then edit the option in /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf with a command like this one:

```
$ echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Comment: thanks to https://forums.linuxmint.com/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=224648&sid=593c6825d5910e0181c4d535c67bf3a0 in Linux mint froum ;-)